# React rerender component while state not changed?

Tags: reactjs, materialize

In [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lkneppz/5/) i created a simple react component with an input field. if an error occure (_handleSubmit) the component will be rerendered with an extra class (invalid). On focus the input, the class will removed by an external script, in this case, by materializecss. if the submit button is clicked next time the state will not change and the component will not rerenderd to DOM, correct? But, how i get the invalid class back? Should i use forceUpdate? What is the right way? Thanks!

```
var Form = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            error: false
        }
    },
    _handleSubmit: function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            error: true
        })
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col s12">
                    <form>
                        <div className="input-field">
                            <input type="text" className={"validate" + (this.state.error ? " invalid" : "")} name="foobar" id="foobar" data-cip-id="foobar" />
                            <label htmlFor="foobar">foobar</label>
                        </div>
                        <button onClick={this._handleSubmit}>submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
             </div>   
            );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Form />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about your question?

Comment: ok, i will try. the component was updated outside of the component by an external script. the "invalid" class was removed with a jquery script. what is the right way to rerender the component, so the component is rendered with the "invalid" class again?

Comment: is it best practice to use ref attribute to solve this?  https://jsfiddle.net/4Lkneppz/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see exactly where it's happening, but you aren't resetting the state when you remove the invalid class on focus.

React doesn't think it needs to redraw because it doesn't know the DOM has changed in the mean time.

Change your code to this

```
var Form = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            error: false
        }
    },
    _handleSubmit: function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            error: true
        })
        console.log(this.state);
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log(this.state);
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col s12">
                    <form>
                        <div className="input-field">
                            <input type="text" key="foobar-{this.state.error}" className={"validate" + (this.state.error ? " invalid" : "")} name="foobar" id="foobar" data-cip-id="foobar" />
                            <label htmlFor="foobar">foobar</label>
                        </div>
                        <button onClick={this._handleSubmit}>submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Form />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

[Click around](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lkneppz/7/) and you'll notice that the error state is always true after the initial submit.

**Update 1**

I've implemented the `onFocus` method to reset the error state. You're making it too complicated using `this.ref`.

```
var Form = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            error: false
        };
    },
    _handleSubmit: function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            error: true
        });
    },
    _resetError: function(error){
        this.setState({
            error: false
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col s12">
                    <form>
                        <div className="input-field">
                            <input type="text" className={"validate" + (this.state.error ? " invalid" : "")} name="foobar" id="foobar" data-cip-id="foobar" onFocus={this._resetError} />
                            <label htmlFor="foobar">foobar</label>
                        </div>
                        <button onClick={this._handleSubmit}>submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
             </div>   
            );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Form />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lkneppz/8/) for details.

Comment: the "invalid" class is removed by materializecss lib. your code don't work. if i resubmit the empty form the invalid class is not added again

Comment: My code does not try to solve the problem, it helps indicate where the issue is. If materializecss changes the DOM, React doesn't know. You need to add a `onFocus` handler to the input which resets `this.state.error` to `false`.

Comment: ahh, ok. so i misunderstood your post, sorry. i solved it with "this.refs" because the form still have an error. maybe u can have a look? https://jsfiddle.net/4Lkneppz/6/